# Elasticsearch search for plurals

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I can't seem to figure out how to get elasticsearch (accessed via pyes) to search plural/singular terms.  For instance, when I enter Monkies, I'd like to get results back that have Belt.  I've looked at [Elasticsearch not returning singular/plural matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064961/elasticsearch-not-returning-singular-plural-matches) but can't seem to make sense of it.  Here's some curl statements

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex -d '
{"index": 
  { "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
       "filter": {
                "myfilter": {
                    "type" : "porter_stem",
                    "language" : "English"
                }
                 },
       "analyzer": {
             "default" : {                    
                 "tokenizer" : "nGram",
                 "filter" : ["lowercase", "myfilter"]
              },
             "index_analyzer" : {                    
                 "tokenizer" : "nGram",
                 "filter" : ["lowercase", "myfilter"]
              },
              "search_analyzer" : {                                                    
                  "tokenizer" : "nGram",
                  "filter" : ["lowercase", "myfilter"]
              }
        }
     }
  }
}
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_mapping -d '{
    "tweet" : {
        "date_formats" : ["yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy"],
        "properties" : {
            "user": {"type":"string"},
            "post_date": {"type": "date"},
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "analyzer": "search_analyzer"}
        }
    }}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/1' -d '{
"user" : "kimchy",
"post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "belt knife is a cool thing"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/2' -d '{
"user" : "alwild",
"post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
"message" : "second message with nothing else"
}'

curl -XGET localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?q=message:belts
```

I've got it to the point where searching for belts give me some results...but now it gives too many results.  What do I have to do to get it to return only that one entry that has "belt" in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, your query is executed against the `_all` field, which uses the standard analyzer, and thus you have no stemming. Try searching with a query such as `name:Monkies`. For production purposes, use the `match` query, which will correctly connect analyzers between your query and the field mapping.

Elasticsearch makes it very easy to compare different analysis settings, by the way. Compare:

```
http://localhost:9200/_analyze?text=Monkies&analyzer=standard
```

vs

```
http://localhost:9200/_analyze?text=Monkies&analyzer=snowball
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you reduce this to a few curl invocations that creates your index with this mapping, indexes some data, and performs a search that shows the results you weren't expecting?

Comment: I've edited the question to include curl statements as well as changed things up a bit.  it is now returning plural results, but it is returning too many/non-relavant results.  thanks for your help.